# How to change method signature/properties to match given execution example?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda, extension-methods

So I have this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, Expression<Func<TModel, ControlPermissionType>> mode)
{
    MvcHtmlString value = null;
    var modeIn = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(
                    mode, htmlHelper.ViewData
                ).Model;
    switch ((ControlPermissionType)modeIn)
    {
        case ControlPermissionType.Read:
            value = htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, new { @readonly = "readonly" });
            break;
        case ControlPermissionType.Edit:
            value = htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression);
            break;
        case ControlPermissionType.Deny:
            value = new MvcHtmlString(string.Empty);
            break;
    }
    return value;
}
```

and this is how I am calling it:

`@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.First().BirthDate, a => a.First().Mode)`

but what I want is:

`@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.First().BirthDate, a.Mode)`

how to do that?

**EDIT:**

or even 
`@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.First().BirthDate)` but in this way how to check if the `a` is implementing interface?

**EDIT2:**

Comment: For the interface part just add `where TModel : IMyInterface`. For the first part, it seems odd that your `TModel` is a collection, I don't really get where you're going with this

Comment: Why not just `ControlPermissionType mode` instead of `Expression<Func<TModel, ControlPermissionType>> mode` and then `switch(mode) {...`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke becouse model is created in `black box` serivice

Comment: If it is in a blackbox, how would you change its parameters ? You have to create a wrapper with the signature you want.

Comment: @Panda as black box i mean that I cannot change data that i get. But i know what i am getting, sadly sometimes we have to work with strange solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.First().BirthDate, a => a.First().Mode)`

Need method signature :

`public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, Expression<Func<TModel, ControlPermissionType>> mode)`

---

`@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.First().BirthDate, a.Mode)`

Need method signature :

`public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, ControlPermissionType mode)`

---

`@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.First().BirthDate)`

Need method signature :

`public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)`

But in this last case, you miss the ControlPermissionType.

By the way, if you try to call your method with `@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.First().BirthDate)`, the compiler error should be self explanatory on which signature method is needed.

Comment: You are right about compiler error, I fixed it by simply changing method name. also `public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, ControlPermissionType mode)` is bad, becouse it does not see `a`